# JSON vs XML - Does XML require a 'local proxy'? What is that?

Tags: c#, javascript, xml, json

I'm reading [this](http://norman.walsh.name/2010/11/17/deprecatingXML) article that compares XML to JSON, and in the comments section, a user mentions the need to use a "local proxy" to access XML.

Can someone explain what a local proxy means in this context?  I'm assuming he means Javascript, but I'm open to understanding what parsers are available in other languages (C#, etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript has a [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) which keeps you from access content from other domains. This prevents the XMLHttpRequest object from being able to retrieve the contents of the XML file from the other domain.

A local proxy is just a simple file that just re-routs the request from your domain to the other domain and fetches the content. This way the same orgin policy is met.

The reason JSON does not run into the restriction is JavaScript, Image, and CSS files can be referenced from other domains. Because JavaScript files can be loaded from other domains, we can use [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) (JSON with Padding) to get the content.

Most people agree that JSONP is not secure since any content can be injected into the JavaScript file. You just have to trust your source that they will not inject any bad content (ads, popups, tracking stuff, etc) into the web page.

Answer (score 2):

This is related to JSONP (as the user states in his comment) which basically defines the ability of JavaScript to execute whatever is provided in the remote source  `<script src="http://url.com/file"></script>`, and gives a browser the ability to retrieve data from remote sources.

I don't like the JSONP term myself, as you could execute XML as well, so the user's comment is actually wrong. You could return something like `run('<some xml></some xml>')` on your server, and then use the built in JavaScript XML parser to get the data that you need - it doesn't need to be JSON.